# MVC 2 = Counting and other Statistics

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using MVC 2 and displaying a grid . Now at the end of this grid i want to show different statistics e.g.

Number of Rows in Grid
Number of Row where One particular column is Null
Sum of Values in one Particular Column

The code part i am using to display the grid is below

```
 <% foreach (var item in Model)
       {%>

            <tr>
            <td> <%: item.tblCourse.CourseName %></td>
            <td> <%: item.NeededHoursPerWeek %> </td>
            <td> <%:item.tblCourseWantedHours.Sum(x=>x.WantedHoursPerWeek)%> </td>
            <td> <%: item.NeededHoursPerWeek - item.tblCourseWantedHours.Sum(x => x.WantedHoursPerWeek)%> </td>

         <td>
             <% foreach (var i in item.tblCourseWantedHours) 

            { %>
                     <%: i.tblPerson.Surename %>
            <% } %>
        </td>   

           <td> <%: item.tblCourse.tblInstitute.InstituteName %> </td>


            </tr>
    <% } %>
```

I have simple controller

public ActionResult Index(string semester)
        {

```
       var allCoursesNeedHours = _pr.FindAllCourseNeededHoursInSemester(semester);


        if (allCoursesNeedHours.Count() == 0)
            return View("NotFound");


        return View(allCoursesNeedHours);
    }
```

and a simple Query in Repository

**public IQueryable FindAllCourseNeededHoursInSemester(string semester)
{
return from allCourses in _db.tblCourseNeededHours orderby allCourses.tblCourse.CourseName where allCourses.Semester == semester select allCourses;
}**

The View Code i have already shown, so can u please guide me at which place i have to make changes to get these statistics. As i am new to MVC 2 so i am confused to get the results

Answer (score 0):

You can use the various aggregate extension methods for LINQ - [Max(), Sum(), Count(), etc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx). But I would recommend doing this in your controller, or even better, in your business logic layer.

You can create a custom class for your Model, and add the aggregates as properties. E.g.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
  var courses = _repository.GetCourses();
  var model = new YourModel(course){SomeAggregate = courses.Count(c => c.X == null)}
  return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of different ways.  Either add the elements that you want to the model so you can bind them to the counts and return them with the view or you could add some counters to your foreach statement that keeps track of the items you need and then display these counter values as the results.   For instance

```
var countRows = 0;
<% foreach (var i in item.tblCourseWantedHours) 
{ %>
     <%: i.tblPerson.Surename %>
     countRows++;
<% } %>
</td>
```

then in a new row display

```
<td>Number of records <%= countRows %>
```

Or whatever you want to call the field.

You could also do it in the Controller or use Linq to do some aggregates.